# Can i do some stateful operations in peek or filter or branch of kafka stream apps?

Tags: filter, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stateful

As we know in kafka stream doc, peek, filter, branch are stateless operations?
However,I wanna do some stateful operations in this processor?
For example, I wanna do some query, and filter messages base the results, can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The operations `peek()`, `filter()`, and `branch()` are inherently stateless. When you say:

> I wanna do some query, and filter messages base the results

than it depends what you want to query? It's possible (but not recommended) to query an "external" API. However, there is no built-in support for it, and there are many corner case to consider to make it robust. Note thought, that querying an external system does not make the operation *stateful*.

If you want to work with state, you can use `transform()` (and siblings) and build custom operators. If you name all your downstream operators (via `Named` and similar) you can use `context.forward(..., To.child(...))` to implement a custom branch. For filtering you can return `null` to not forward anything.

Not sure what a stateful peek() would be used for, but you could also do that.

Depending on the use-case, it's also possible to implement a "stateful filter" via a stream-table join or stream-globalTable join.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best ways to do this is using [table lookup](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining) using `KStream#...join` or using [Processor API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html) to get access to the underlying state store (using a `KStream#transformValues`).

You could do that but the code will be very nasty (would not recommend this), but you can only get a read only access to a `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore` after Stream state had move from REBALANCING to RUNNING:

```
kafkaStreams.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
    if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING && oldState == KafkaStreams.State.REBALANCING) {
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Object, Object> kvStore = kafkaStreams.store("stateStore", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
        //assign this kvStore to some place so you can later using this referrer access this in filter or in peek
    }
});
```

Comment: KStream#transformValues or KStream#transform?Buecause,the latter can return null,which can terminate forwarding the messages,that is filter function?!

Comment: @zydzjy Yes, KStream#transform will also work as a filter when you return null KeyValue like you said, but beware that KStream#transform will mark a data re-partition and will be triggered when you call some operator like join, groupByKey,...

Comment: Using "Interactive Queries" does not sound like as a working solution.

Comment: Yes, the elegant solution is still using Processor API or table lookup

Comment: @TuyenLuong so how can i use transformValues as filter function?Thanks！

Comment: @zydzjy one way you can do this is return a null value then filter out record with a null value in the downstream using KStream#filter(), if it sounds too complicated then just use KStream#transform()